# Finding users with highest percentage of accepted or top voted answers?

Tags: discussion, support, data-explorer

I am attempting to improve [a data.SE query to find users with the highest percentage of accepted answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/workplace/query/210970/users-with-highest-accept-rate-of-their-answers) to include a percentage where the answer is not accepted, but highest voted.

This query works well for the first part - accepted answers - but does not address the situation where the answer is:

- not accepted
- highest scored

I was trying this as an additional case clause... but it seems more complicated than I can figure out.

```
 --this really doesn't work.. at all
  sum(case 
    when 
        q.AcceptedAnswerId <> a.Id
        and a.Score = select MAX(Score) from Posts ps where ps.ID=q.ID
    then 
        1 
    else 
        0
    end) AS NumHighestNotAccept,
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Having the query there doesn't really work. Instead I forked yours to [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/workplace/query/309381/users-with-highest-accept-rate-of-their-answers?MinAnswers=10) and added an left outer join to get a set of the highest scoring answers per question.

```
-- Users with highest accept rate of their answers
-- Does not count self-answers. 
-- Shows users with at least @MinAnswers answers.

DECLARE @MinAnswers int = ##MinAnswers##

SELECT TOP 100
  u.Id AS [User Link],
  count(*) AS NumAnswers,
  sum(case 
    when 
        TopAnswer.id is not null
    then 
        1 
    else 
        0
    end) AS NumHighestNotAccept,
  sum(case when q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id then 1 else 0 end) AS NumAccepted,
  (sum(case when q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id then 1 else 0 end)*100.0/count(*)) AS AcceptedPercent
FROM Posts a
INNER JOIN Users u ON u.Id = a.OwnerUserId
INNER JOIN Posts q ON a.ParentId = q.Id
left outer join (
 -- get the id's from the answers 
 -- on a question ...
 select ps.id
 from Posts ps 
 -- that have a score
 where score = (select max(score)  -- maxium of all answers
                from posts pas 
                -- on this question
                where ps.parentid = pas.parentid)
) as TopAnswer 
     -- for a specific answer
     on topanswer.id = a.id 
WHERE 
  (q.OwnerUserId <> u.Id OR q.OwnerUserId IS NULL)   --no self answers
GROUP BY u.Id
HAVING count(*) >= @MinAnswers
ORDER BY AcceptedPercent DESC
       , NumAnswers DESC
```